# Why is "." replaced by "$" in classpath of java.lang.ClassNotFoundException?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have an FXML Document where I am using a custom control `ImageButton` it is stored in the package `net.aninnovation.baseUtility.view.ImageButton` This contains 3 files 
*ImageButton.class*, *ImageButton.fxml* and *ImageButton.css*. The `.class` file is the controller, the `.fmxl` is the FXML document and the `.css` file is the stylesheet.

Now I am creating an FXML document in the package `net.aninnovation.csp.main`. The name of the file is *Default.fxml*. This is basically a `VBox` as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import ...........................?>//Other required Imports
<?import net.aninnovation.baseUtility.view.ImageButton.ImageButton?>

<VBox id="defaultPanel" fx:id="defaultPanel" styleClass="centerBox" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="net.aninnovation.CSP.main.DefaultController">
    <children>
        <FlowPane>
            <children>
                .
                .
                .
                . //Other 
                . //Components
                .
                <ImageButton/>
                .
                . //Other
                . //Components
                .
            </children>
        </FlowPane>
    </children>
   <stylesheets>
      <URL value="@Default.css" />
   </stylesheets>
</VBox>
```

When I try to load this file in **SceneBuilder** it gives the following Exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.aninnovation.baseUtility.view.ImageButton$ImageButton
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
>     ... 20 more

Here I find that though I had imported `net.aninnovation.baseUtility.view.ImageButton`**.**`ImageButton`, the Exception states `net.aninnovation.baseUtility.view.ImageButton`**$**`ImageButton`. Now why is the `.` being replaced by `$`? Is there something wrong I have done?

The constructor of `ImageButton` class is loading the FXML document as here:

```
public ImageButton() {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ImageButton.fxml"));
    loader.setRoot(this);
    loader.setController(this);
    try {
        loader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

**ImageButton.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath?>

<fx:root stylesheets="@ImageButton.css" type="Button" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <graphic>
        <VBox>
            <children>
                <SVGPath fx:id="svgImage" />
                <Label fx:id="label" />
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </graphic>
</fx:root>
```

These are located in the package `net.aninnovation.baseUtility.view.ImageButton`. As stated earlier there are 3 files in the location **ImageButton.class**, **ImageButton.fxml** and **ImageButton.css**

When I moved the ImageButton to package `net.aninnovation.csp.main` and `net.aninnovation.csp.main.imageButton`. I have got the error as:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.aninnovation.csp$main$ImageButton
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
>     ... 20 more

and

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.aninnovation.csp$main$imageButton$ImageButton
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
>     ... 20 more

Comment: I don't know if this causes the problem, but package names should be lowercase.

Comment: Typically the `$` is used to represent inner classes. Not sure why it thinks it's looking for an inner class. Do you have the same problem if the package is named `net.aninnovation.baseUtility.view.imageButton` (note lowercase i)? I can't imagine this actually solving it though...

Comment: @Krease I had moved the code for `ImageButton` around in several packages like `net.aninnovation.baseUtility.imageButton` and also `net.aninnovation.csp.main` and `net.aninnovation.csp.main.imageButton`. I have got very unusual error that I have posted.

Comment: It isn't replaced in the CLASSPATH. It is replaced in the class *name*.

Comment: @EJP so how can it be corrected?

Comment: There is nothing here that needs correction except the missing class.

Comment: @EJP but I have all the required files in the required location. I have already stated in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason's could be `net.aninnovation.baseUtility.view.ImageButton.ImageButton` is a NestedClass of `net.aninnovation.baseUtility.view.ImageButton`

For Example:

```
public class Number  {
    class NestedNumber {

    }
}
```

When this code gets compiled, java generates 2 files. 
Namely:

1. Number$NestedNumber.class
2. Number.class

But, when you access in code (for imports) you still use Number.NestedNumber instead of $.
However for Reflection you use $.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Class<?> forName = Class.forName("Number$NestedNumber");
        System.out.println(forName);
    }
```

Comment: Ok, So why does it throw a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`?

Comment: Can you paste the code for `ImageButton`?
Also how your accessing `FXMLLoader.importClass`

Comment: I basically do not have a nested class here as you could see from the code.

Comment: Can you paste the package structure as well? Also, What are the contents of the ImageButton.fxml file?